# jQuery - append row to two tables

Tags: jquery

So, i'm getting some json data and iterating over the result and populating a table based on the resulting values. I actually want to populate two tables with the same results and have tried the following code:

```
$.getJSON( "helpers.php", {
})
.done(function( rows ) {
    $.each(rows, function() {
        // populate the table
        var row = $('<tr>');
        var position = $('<td>').html(this.position);    
        var teamname = $('<td>').html(this.team);
        var points = $('<td>').html(this.points);
        row.append(position,teamname,points);
        $('#table-one').append(row);
        $('#table-two').append(row);  
    });
});
```

It works if I comment out either of the tables to append, so i.e. only appending to one or the other, but not both. Not sure why this doesnt work, but any explanations and code fixes appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/clone/

You just have to change the last two lines:

```
row.appendTo('#table-one');
row.clone().appendTo('#table-two');
```

Comment: even better - never knew about clone()

Answer (score 1):

When you `.append()` an existing element, the element is moved. Try this:

```
row.append(position,teamname,points);
var rowHtml = row.wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
$('#table-one').append(rowHtml);
$('#table-two').append(rowHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the same DOM node to two different parents.  You need to create two matching HTML/DOM structures and append one to each table:

```
function createRow(positionVal, teamVal, pointsVal) {
        var row = $('<tr>');
        var position = $('<td>').html(positionVal);    
        var teamname = $('<td>').html(teamVal);
        var points = $('<td>').html(pointsVal);
        row.append(position,teamname,points);

        return row;
}

$.getJSON( "helpers.php", {
})
.done(function( rows ) {
    $.each(rows, function() {
        // populate the table
        $('#table-one').append(createRow(this.position, this.team, this.points));
        $('#table-two').append(createRow(this.position, this.team, this.points));  
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, nice approach with the function but the answer from Jason used less lines of code so went with that option :-)

Comment: no worries!  I didn't know about `.wrap()` which is awesome!

Comment: everyday is a school day. certainly for me anyway!